# android sdk , error : java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state

Tags: java, android

Basically i am trying to remove the icon of an application and let it be still installed , using this example : http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/removing-app-icon-launcher

The code i am trying to run using the android studio is :

```
package com.example.root.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.ComponentName ;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager ;

public class java_test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_test);

        ComponentName componentToDisable =
                new ComponentName("com.nll.acr",
                        "com.nll.acr.LauncherActivity");

        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentToDisable,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
```

the manifest xml autogenerated file contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_java_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:context="com.example.root.myapplication.java_test">



    <TextView
        android:exported="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error i keep getting is

```
EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.root.myapplication/com.example.root.myapplication.java_test}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=1300, uid=10154, package uid=10150
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
```

...

I have looked over the internet , and foud that i have to put somewere in the xml this  'android:enabled="true"' , but that just pops another error :

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class service

Update :
I have commented out the line

```
   getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
            componentToDisable,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Now it is working fine

But i need that line to work in order to be able to remove the shortcut

UPDATE 3 if I try this :

then the compiler says that "layout_height" and "layout_width" are missing

if I try :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <TextView
        android:exported="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It complains that "Error inflating class activity"

UPDATE 4 :

if I try :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then the compiler says that "layout_height" and "layout_width" are missing

Comment: did you check CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE is granted?

Comment: also why   android:exported="true" in Textview?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<activity
   android:name=".LoginActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" 
   android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

use `android:exported="true"` inside `manifest` not in `layout`

Comment: still facing  same issue?

Comment: yes : Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class activity

Comment: Ganesh , i know i did wrong the "<activity ../>" where do i put it ?

Comment: I updated the post with UPDATE 3 and 4 , I have tried the "<activity ../>" both inside RelativeLayout , and got different results

Comment: add this in AndroidManifest.xml not in layouts... 3&4 are layout files

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.2.2

Comment: the xml file is named activity_java_test.xml , and the java file is named java_test.java , this is al lin Android Studio , I don't know where to edit the  AndroidManifest.xml file